# StreamlitAPIException: Unable to convert object of type <class 'str'> to pandas.DataFrame

Tags: chatbot, streamlit, session-state

I am trying to save and display a tabular output of chatbot using session state, but getting the error:
StreamlitAPIException: Unable to convert object of type <class 'str'> to pandas.DataFrame.

I have tried
st.write(st.table(message["content"])), but it is not working.